# What should be the capacitor values for cascaded voltage regulators?

Tags: capacitor, voltage-regulator

I have an LD1086DT50TR 5V voltage regulator, which is followed by an LD1117DT33TR 3.3V voltage regulator. The LD1086* datasheet specifies a 10uF capacitor at the regulator's output, while the LD1117* datasheet specifies a 0.1uF at the regulator's input. When I connect the 5V regulator to the 3.3V regulator, what value of capacitor should I put between them?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking you can go higher than the recommended value, but not lower. So use a 10uF (or greater) between the two regulators.

The datasheet recommends 10uF (minimum) for stability of the LD1086. This is a rather old regulator, an LDO type and the example schematics show electrolytic capacitors. If you intend to use a ceramic capacitor you have two potential issues:

1. The ESR may be too low (the capacitor may be *too* good) for stability of the regulator. Recommended to put a few ohms in series with a ceramic capacitor.
2. A ceramic capacitor will have a significant voltage coefficient and may have a fraction of the "nameplate" value at 5V bias. Check the detailed data sheets. You might have to use a much larger value or several 10uF caps in parallel. Generally (physically) smaller capacitor are worse in this regard.